# Move side navbar when i change the page direction to rtl

Tags: html, css

I have a page which has one sidebar to open different pages. It is working as desired with direction left to right but I want to move this sidebar to the right side when i change the page direction to right to left.

Following is the HTML of my page.

I have searched on internet but I did not get any solution.
From my side I have tried to change the direction of the page in HTML but it is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <!--<meta charset="utf-8">-->
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/sidenavbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/tabs.css">
    <title>Bootstrap Side NavBar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid pl-4 pt-2 ml-auto">
      <div class="row d-flex d-md-block flex-nowrap wrapper pr-2">
        <div class="col-md-3 float-left col-1 pl-0 pr-2 width show collapse" id="sidebar" aria-expanded="true"> <!--"collapse" removed from class to show when page loaded,
          add "collapse" in the class to hide on page load -->
          <div class="list-group border-0 card text-center text-md-left">
            <div style="text-align:center;">
              <img src="images/userid.jpg" style="width:40%;border-radius:50%"></img>
              <h3>User</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="line"> </div>
            <a href="#manifest" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fa fa-truck"></i>
              <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Manifest/Operation</span>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="manifest">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#manifest">Upload Truck Pre Arrival</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#manifest">Generate DO</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#manifest">Check In Gate</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#manifest">Check Out Gate</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#manifest">Generate Gatepass</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#billing" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fa fa-dollar"></i>
              <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Billing</span>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="billing">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#billing">Charge/Service Codes</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#billing">Vat Setup</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#billing">Generate Invoice</a>
            </div>

            <a href="#commercial" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Commercial</span>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="commercial">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#commercial">Customer Details</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#commercial">Contract Details</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#commercial">Creating Tariffs</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar">
              <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
              <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Finance</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#admin" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>
              <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Admin Tools</span>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="admin">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#commercial">Modules</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#commercial">Menu Items</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#commercial">User Group</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#commercial">Login Users</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#commercial">Bilingual Interface Setup</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#commercial">Bilingual Message Setup</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#commercial">System Codes</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#settings" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fa fa-sliders"></i>
              <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Settings</span>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="settings">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#settings">Company Profile</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="line"> </div>
        </div>
        <main class="col-md-12 col px-5 pl-md-2 pt-0 main mx-auto" style="background-color:white;border-radius:4px">
          <div class="row pl-md-1 pl-0">
            <div class="col-md-1 pl-md-0">
              <a href="#" data-target="#sidebar" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true">
                <i class="fa fa-navicon fa-2x py-2 p-1"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 pl-md-0 pl-1 pt-2" style="text-align:right">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 pl-md-0 pl-0">
              <div class="pt-3">
                <h6>Saudi Development & Export Services Co. Ltd.</h6>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 pl-0 pr-0" style="text-align:right">
              <div class="language pt-3">
                <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">
                  <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                  English
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <hr>

            <div class="row pl-md-1 pl-1">
              <div class="col-md-12 pl-0">
                <p class="lead">DashBoard</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="os-tabs-controls">
              <ul class="nav nav-pills upper">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#para" aria-expanded="true">Item1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#control" aria-expanded="false">Item2</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="para" class="tab-pane active" aria-expanded="true">
              <div class="row pl-md-1 pl-0">
                <div class="col-md-10 pl-1 pt-1" style="border-top:3px solid black">
                  <button role="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" aria-expanded="true">
                    horizontal collapsible
                  </button>
                  <div id="demo" class="width collapse show" aria-expanded="true">
                    <div class="list-group"> <!--style="width:600px;"-->
                      <p>
                        Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
                        Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2 pl-md-0 pl-1 pt-1" style="border-top:3px solid black">
                  <button role="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2" aria-expanded="true">
                    vertical collapsible
                  </button>
                  <div id="demo2" class="height collapse show" aria-expanded="true">
                    <div class="list-group"> <!--style="width:200px;"-->
                      <p>
                        Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="control" class="tab-pane" aria-expanded="false">
              <div class="row pl-md-1 pl-0 pt-2" style="border-top:3px solid black">
                <div class="col-md-2 pl-1">
                  <label>User ID:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 pl-md-0 pl-1">
                  <input type="text" name="username"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row pl-md-1 pl-0">
                <div class="col-md-2 pl-1">
                  <label>User Password:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 pl-md-0 pl-1">
                  <input type="password" name="password"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row pl-md-1 pl-0">
                <div class="col-md-2 pl-1">
                  <label>User Profile:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 pl-md-0 pl-1">
                  <input type="text" name="profile"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>


/* CSS Document */
body {
  background-color:#599cff;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica;
  /*direction:rtl;*/
  /*font-family: times-new-roman;*/
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
    /*margin: 5px 0;*/
}

#sidebar {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 3;
    /*direction:rtl;*/
    /*height:100vh;*/
    /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
}

#sidebar h3 {
  font-size:.8em;
  color:#F0F8FF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h6 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color:#a9a9a9;
  font-size:.7em;
  font-weight:bold;
}

#sidebar .list-group {
    max-width: 300px;
    background-color: #006666;/*#333;*/
    min-height: 100vh;
}

#sidebar i {
    margin-right: 6px;
}

#sidebar .list-group-item {
    border-radius: 4;
    background-color: #006666;/*#333;*/
    color: #F0F8FF;/*#333;#ccc;*/
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    font-size: .9em;
    /*border-color: #0d8686;#2c2c2c;*/
    #F0F8FF-space: nowrap;
}

#sidebar .list-group-item:hover {
  background-color: #F0F8FF;
  color: #333;
}

/* highlight active menu */
#sidebar .list-group-item:not(.collapsed) {
    background-color: #73abab;/*#222;*/
    /*border-color:#99cccc;#006666;*/
}

/* closed state */
#sidebar .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="false"]::after {
  content: " \f0d7";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

/* open state */
#sidebar .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background-color: #006666;/*#222;*/
  color: #F0F8FF;
  /*border-color:#99cccc;*/
}
#sidebar .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"]::after {
  content: " \f0da";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

/* level 1*/
#sidebar .list-group .collapse .list-group-item,
#sidebar .list-group .collapsing .list-group-item  {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

/* level 2*/
#sidebar .list-group .collapse > .collapse .list-group-item,
#sidebar .list-group .collapse > .collapsing .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

/* level 3*/
#sidebar .list-group .collapse > .collapse > .collapse .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
    #sidebar {
        min-width: 35px;
        max-width: 40px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: visible;
        transition: all 0.25s ease;
        transform: translateX(-45px);
        /*position: fixed;*/
    }

    #sidebar.show {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    #sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar{ width: 0px; }

    #sidebar, #sidebar .list-group {
        min-width: 35px;
        overflow: visible;
    }

    /* overlay sub levels on small screens */
    #sidebar .list-group .collapse.show, #sidebar .list-group .collapsing {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 190px;
        top: 0;
    }


    #sidebar .list-group > .list-group-item {
        text-align: center;
        padding: .75rem .5rem;
    }

    #sidebar h3 {
      font-size:.50em;
    }
    /* hide caret icons of top level when collapsed */
    #sidebar .list-group > .list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"]::after,
    #sidebar .list-group > .list-group-item[aria-expanded="false"]::after {
        display:none;
    }
}

.collapse.show {
  visibility: visible;
}
.collapsing {
  visibility: visible;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: height, visibility;
  /*-moz-transition-property: height, visibility;*/
  transition-property: height, visibility;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.collapsing.width {
  -webkit-transition-property: width, visibility;
  /*-o-transition-property:width, visibility;*/
  transition-property: width, visibility;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is your sidebar:

```
<div class="col-md-3 float-left col-1 pl-0 pr-2 width show collapse" id="sidebar" aria-expanded="true">
```

Replace `float-left` with `float-right`

So sidebar after replacing will be:

```
<div class="col-md-3 float-right col-1 pl-0 pr-2 width show collapse" id="sidebar" aria-expanded="true">
```

This will fix the problem on wide screens, the problem still need to be fixed on the mobile screens, now you need to reverse the position of the flex box (`wrapper`)

This is your wrapper:

```
<div class="row d-flex d-md-block flex-nowrap wrapper pr-2">
```

add `flex-row-reverse` into `class=""` attribute:

```
<div class="row d-flex d-md-block flex-nowrap wrapper pr-2 flex-row-reverse">
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot, its working but still i have the problem with my header which is not aligning properly, following is the HTML for that.

Comment: <div class="col-md-8 pl-md-0 pl-5">
              <div class="pt-3">
                <h6>Saudi Development & Export Services Co. Ltd.</h6>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 pl-0 pr-5" style="text-align:left">
              <div class="language pt-1">
                <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">
                  <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                  English
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>

Comment: sorry i am new to stack overflow, so may be i am not properly using it.

Comment: and if i want to change the direction dynamically based on the button click, then how to do it.

Comment: hi, how can i fix the issue on mobile screens, please help me i am stuck here

Comment: Hi, maybe you can ask another question with some more details about the exact problem